# How to sort cells in tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting, uilabel

How to sort cells in tableView?

---

I have struct and array:

```
struct Converter {
        let title: String
        let kf: Double
    }

    let converterAtmo = [
        Converter(title: "Атмосферы", kf: 1),
        Converter(title: "Бары", kf: 365.2422),
        Converter(title: "Мм.рт.ст.", kf: 11.999998),
        Converter(title: "Паскали", kf: 525948.77),
        Converter(title: "Фунт./кв.дюйм", kf: 52.177457)]
```

---

in `CellAtRow` func:

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! resultTableViewCell

            let item = converterAtmo[indexPath.row]

            cell1.nameResult.text = item.title
            cell1.labelResult.text = String(item.kf * atmosfera)


            return cell1
```

---

And finally `@IBAction`:

```
 @IBAction func sortAlphabet(_ sender: Any) {

        let itemSort = converterAtmo

        itemSort.sorted { $0.title < $1.title }

        self.tableView2.reloadData()

    }
```

But it's not working...

What is my problem?

Comment: This is not easily reproducible outside of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to declare `converterAtmo` as `var` instead of `let` so that you can modify it.

Then replace:

```
itemSort.sorted { $0.title < $1.title }
```

with:

```
self.converterAtmo = itemSort.sorted { $0.title < $1.title }
```

In your current implementation you sort a copy of your model (`itemSort` is just a copy of your `self.converterAtmo`), so it does not have any effect on the model behind the tableView. You need to set that sorted array back to tableView data model.

Or even better, you can just use this:

```
@IBAction func sortAlphabet(_ sender: Any) {
    // `sort` method will sort the converterAtmo (`sorted` method leaves the original 
    // array untouched and returns a sorted copy)
    self.converterAtmo.sort { $0.title < $1.title }
    self.tableView2.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In :

```
let itemSort = converterAtmo
itemSort.sorted { $0.title < $1.title }
```

You are not actually sorting your array. You are copying it in 'itemSort' and not doing anything with it.