# How to hide UIView() when custom UITextField is tapped (programmatically)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I faced one problem which I don't understand and solve in any way. When the textField is activated, the keyboard is displayed when the buttons of numbers in keyboard are pressed, my stackView, which is located in the middle of the screen, should hide and my tableView should rise up, having an indent from the headView of 36 points. When I delete text in the textField, everything should return to the standard view as in the screenshot. I used **UIKit** **programmatically** **without StoryBoard** and **SnapKit for constraints.** What method should I use here? textField delegate or UIView.animate {} or smth.Could you help me pls.

My **UITextField is greenColor**, I made it like view just for sample and demonstration.

```
final class HeaderView: UIView {
   
   // There are contains UIImageView & UITextField
   // UIImageView has yellow color in screenShot
   // UITextField has green color in screenShot
   ..........
}

final class LeftView: UIView {
  
  // Contains textLabel and IconImg
  ...........
}

final class RightView: UIView {
  
  // Contains textLabel and IconImg
  ...........
}
```

and call them in my UIViewController:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

        private let headerLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
            label.text = "Hello World!"
            label.textColor = .black
            return label
        }()
 
        // Calling my custom views
        let headView = HeaderView()
        let leftView = LeftView()
        let rightView = RightView()
        
        let stackView: UIStackView = {
           let stackView = UIStackView()
           stackView.axis = .horizontal
           stackView.alignment = .center
           stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
           return stackView
        }()

        // After that, I created UITableView
        let tableView: UITableView = {
            let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            return tableView
        }()

        // ViewDidLoad
        override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
           
           tableView.delegate = self
           tableView.dataSource = self

           self.setupUI()
        }

        func setupUI() {
           self.setSubviews()
           self.setConstraints()
        }

        func setSubviews() {
           self.view.addSubview(headerLabel)
           self.view.addSubview(headView)
           self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(leftView)
           self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rightView)
           self.view.addSubview(stackView)
           self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        }

        private func setConstraints() {
    
           headerLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
              make.top.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).offset(30)
              make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
           }
    
           headView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
              make.top.equalTo(self.headerLabel.snp.bottom).offset(24)
              make.leading.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).offset(16)
              make.trailing.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).offset(-16)
              make.height.equalTo(56)
          }
    
          stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
              make.top.equalTo(self.headView.snp.bottom).offset(16)
              make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
          }
    
          leftView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
              make.top.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.top)
              make.leading.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.leading)
              make.bottom.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.bottom)
              make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 163, height: 88))
          }
    
          rightView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
              make.top.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.top)
              make.trailing.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.trailing)
              make.bottom.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.bottom)
              make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 163, height: 88))
          }
    
          tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
             make.top.equalTo(self.stackView.snp.bottom).offset(36)
             make.leading.trailing.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
             make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
          }
      }
}

extension UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
     }

     public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
       return cell
    }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide UIView when a text or number is typed in a textfield, you must add target to your UITextfield like you would add a target to UIButton, But, for a UITextfield the UIControl.Event has to be changed (.editingChanged).

For example:

```
let textField = UITextFiled()

override func viewDidLoad() {

  // Add all the required stuffs of UItextfield and add the following code

       textField(self, action: #selector(txtValueChanged(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)

}

@objc func txtValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {

  // You have to hide LeftView,RightView . So, add this code

      leftView.isHidden = true
      rightView.isHidden = true

}
```

This code will hide the views when a character is typed in UITextfield.

Comment: What about tableView? That should be raise up. And my textField is declared inside another custom view. HeaderView()

Comment: I have viewed your code where you have set constraints for the content inside UIStackView, there is no need for it , Just remove all constraint and give only the height for both rightView and leftView, the UIStackView will automatically align the views based on the axis and spacing you gave. And after that when you hide all the views inside a UIStackview , the stack view will shrink and the tableview automatically rises up.

Comment: To set target to the textfield inside the custom view, use this in your viewDidLoad,  "headerView.textField(self, action: #selector(txtValueChanged(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)"

Comment: Okay thank you for sharing your point of view. As a demonstration, I highlighted two views with colors, but in fact these views contain pictures, labels and buttons. Its fixed size should be on demand. How to resolve in this situation ?

Comment: I need to know whether you will add more views inside the UIStackView or will it have only two, based on this I have a solution.

Comment: It have only two views inside UIStackView

Comment: In that case, you can create a View X and and add the rightView and leftview inside the created View X, add constraints to rightView and leftView, But don't add constraints to the view X, just add that view X inside the stack view that you already have and give vertical axis to the StackView and now in the function used as target add this line "viewX.isHidden = true" , so when a character is typed , the view X will be hidden and stackView will shrink and tableview rises.

Comment: Okey, tell me please if I arise of number in the textField, stackView should back in the default position, how can I should in this situation, just if / else?

Comment: In your target action, write a condition like this -  " if textField.text?.count == x { viewX.isHidden = false } " . This works when a number of character inside the textField is x(x can be 0 or any other value). The view will be visible and everything will go back to its previous state once the condition is met.

Comment: Can you pls tell me how can I sort the data which collect inside tableviewcell. For instance my textfield contains inside the custom HeaderView(). I need to tap the textfield type some numbers, and result tableviewcell should sort and display the data. Do I need here to use MVVM architecture?

Comment: It has noting to to do with the architecture. If you are using MVC its fine, how do you want to sort your data?  There are a lot of sorting functions, you can get it on stack overflow , first you have to run those sorting functions on the array which populates the tableview based on your requirement  and the reload the tableview. If you want the sorting to occur on a value change in textfield, use the above method. Call the sorting function in the target action of the textfield.

Comment: Could you please share it, actually I don't understand how can I sort my tableviewcell by typing number in the textfield. Because it locates another file. I mean it should not have direct access, i need an intermediary between the text field and the table cells

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689631/how-to-sort-cells-in-tableview) is one example, how exactly do you need to sort(is it like alphabetically or something else), If the doubt is not clarified, can you post it as another question with elaborated explanation of your requirement.